# HAProxy proxy forwarding to external HTTPS, with a URL rewrite

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to get HAProxy to behave like a HTTP proxy, except for URLS passed in should be forwarded to an external service which only provides a HTTPS REST based proxy API.

So something like:

```
# HAProxy running on 127.0.0.1:8888
curl -x http://127.0.0.1:8888 http://www.example.com
```

would use my HAProxy server running on `127.0.0.1:8888` to forward the request for `http://www.example.com` to a third party HTTP REST based proxy API, using the format:  `https://url-privacy-service.com/api/v1/?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY&url=http://www.example.com`

**The purpose of doing this would be to allow the REST based `https://url-privacy-service.com` to be used as a standard HTTP proxy on various devices, with the help of HAProxy sitting in front.**

Here's what I've cobbled together so far in my HAProxy config:

```
frontend urlprivacy
        bind 127.0.0.1:8888
        use_backend urlprivacy-backend

backend urlprivacy-backend
        acl https ssl_fc
        http-request set-uri https://url-privacy-service.com/api/v1/?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&url=https://%[req.hdr(Host)]%[path]?%[query]
        http-request set-method GET
        server url-privacy-service.com:443 check-ssl ssl verify none
```

Why I try issuing the request via `curl -x http://127.0.0.1:8888 http://www.example.com`, I'm met with the error response:

```
<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>
```

I am able to invoke the `url-privacy-service.com`'s REST API successfully, so I know their service is working as expected.  Thus I know the HAProxy configuration is obviously wrong, I'm just unsure of what to do in order to make it right.  If needed, I can run other http proxies (eg tinyproxy) to help facilitate.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, you just need to configure your server to use SSL and update some of your config. Here are the changes

1. Listen on 443 and reference SSL pem file (you should be able to listen on a different port but I haven't tested, you can also redirect http to https [see here](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/redirect-http-to-https-with-haproxy/))
2. Use set-path and set-header in backend http-request and sni in server

```
frontend urlprivacy
        bind 127.0.0.1:443 ssl crt <path/to/your/cert.pem>
        use_backend urlprivacy-backend

backend urlprivacy-backend
        http-request set-path /api/v1/?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&url=https://%[req.hdr(Host)]%[path]?%[query]
        http-request set-header Host url-privacy-service.com
        http-request set-method GET 
        server url-privacy-service.com:443 sni str(url-privacy-service.com) check-ssl ssl verify none
```

The previous code breaks because when you call with HTTP, you are passing through the unencrypted payload to the server. By making these changes you can create the correct call for the HTTPS server `url-privacy-service.com`

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if this can even be achieved. If a https request is given through port 443 it requires SSL. If the SSL of the https request is available we can just add a redirect rule in the ssl frontend for the host as follow:

```
redirect scheme http if { hdr(Host) -i https://url-privacy-service.com } { ssl_fc }
```

For you to redirect to https, you would probably need to bind to port 443 using a proper ssl certificate. This is the basic expectation of a browser.

***NOTE***: the above redirect rule is just an illustration, might not work without a proper SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do what you are suggesting since a forward proxy will not be able to look at the payload it just pipes through the data with the information provided in the `CONNECT` command, the payload would be encrypted in HTTPS case therefore the information such as the path and query is not available for HAProxy to make the connection on behalf of the client to the third party application.